# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BCBio'

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to run a script that converts gff file to vista format. This script needs to run to-gff script as a part of it. The problem is in running 'to-gff'. Although I can see bcbio installed when doing 'pip list' --> `bcbio-gff                     0.7.0`, it still shows the error `'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BCBio'`. A part of the to-gff script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.8
"""
Generate gff file from EMBL/Genbank for QUAST
"""

__title__        = 'to_gff'
__version__      = '0.1.1'
__description__  = "Generate gff file from EMBL/Genbank for QUAST"
__author__       = 'Mitchell Stanton-Cook'
__license__      = 'ECL 2.0'
__author_email__ = "m.stantoncook@gmail.com"
__url__         = 'http://github.com/mscook/to_gff'


import sys, os, traceback, argparse
import time

from BCBio import GFF
from Bio import SeqIO
```

Should I install bcbio in some other way?
Also, when I type `which python` it returns `/home/richa/anaconda3/bin/python`
Is there a connection that I am missing?

I also tried installing BCBio as mentioned in this link: [BCBio installation](https://bcbio-nextgen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contents/installation.html) and it got installed in a different location: `/home/user/bcbio/anaconda/envs/python3.6` and there was same error after running the script: `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: Does `python  -m pip show` also show bcbio-gff?